# New page in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

this is my situation:

1. I have a report with 10 (or more) items in detail area
2. I have a large text field that I would like to span across multiple pages (this text has nothing to do with items)
3. I am not able to create another page because all of my items fit nicely on the first page

How can I create (force) a new page to contain only some variable (static) text, on the page footer? In other words, how can I create a new page with no items?

Answer (score 4):

In iReport Designer 4.1.1

The Break element is inside the Palette window.

You can select if you want to break the page or column

Answer (score 4):

Palette > Report Elements > Break -> **Page break**. 
Everything what is after this Break is printed on next Page.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be specific about iReport version.

In 2.0.5, from the Edit menu choose "Insert page/column break"
Put it in the band where you want to break. In the Properties dialog, make sure the Break Type is set to "Page"

I usually prefer to use it with "Print with expression" so it does not make an empty page when i dont have an empty report already.

Answer (score 1):

In 5.5.0
You can add large text field to the Summary band.
Then,click report name in Report Inspector find "Summary on new page" in Properties then check.
So you have new page after detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the page size of detail band in Ireport, To increase size go to xml tab

and search for

```
 <detail>
    <band height="482"/>
```

and add

```
  <detail>
  <band height="600" splitType="Immediate">
```

After that i think you may able to see another page.I have tested this method with only Summary band, if it does not work copy all the item in summary band.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Break that you will get from Palette.

And if you want to add some text in the footer of second page only then you can't do it with the Brak only.

In that situation you need to use PrintWhen expression suits for your requirement.