# create new page iReport 5.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to create a new page in iReport 5.5.0.

I've been looking at [New page in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510819/new-page-in-ireport) and tried to:

1. add another detail band
2. set my report to A4-size
3. add a page break

None of these work and I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong... The PDF is even a LOT bigger then the "A4" size I've told it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.
"Ignore pagination" in the report properties was true..